# If email is already taken, update the user concerned Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm currently building an app which is working with Devise. Some actions allows the users to invite other users by entering their emails. But sometimes the users are not registered yet.

To avoid a multiplication of tables and conditions (between registered and non-registered users), I chose to create empty User (with email, id, and registered(false) variables). This allows me to always use the same user for different invitations, even if the user is not yet registered.

The idea is that when the user registers, it automatically retrieves all the information previously recorded by other users (in this case invitations)

However, Devise email is defined by default as unique (across method :validatable).

During registration, I need to set the following condition:

```
if email does not exist
  New User
elsif email exist && not registred
  Update User with this email
else
  message:'email already token'
end
```

I tried several solutions like:

*RegistrationsController#Create :*

```
@previous_account = User.where(email: params[:user][:email]).first
if @previous_account == nil && @previous_account.registred != true
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
else 
  # This update the user with his password and other information, but keeping the same id (to keep all the previous invitations)
  @previous_account.update(params[:user])
end
```

or

*User Model:*

before_create :verif_exist

```
def verif_exist
  pre_user = User.where(email: self.email).first
  if pre_user != nil && pre_user.registred != true 
    pre_user.update(encrypted_password: self.encrypted_password, registred: true)
  else
    self.save
  end
end
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, if anyone has the same specificities in their app, I would love to see your solution.

Comment: Have you tried implementing - https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: Thanks for  your answer @Michael, I will look at it when github will come back